# Converting voting district GeoID to approximate zip code?

Tags: data, data-cleaning

How do you convert a "GEOID", representing a US voting district, to an approximate ZIP code?

I've extracted the GEOIDs from the JSON published by the [New York Times](https://github.com/TheUpshot/presidential-precinct-map-2020) of the results of the 2020 US election, and I'm trying to run an analysis based on ZIP code.

I know the GEOIDs don't have a 1-to-1 correlation to ZIP codes, but that's ok. I only need a rough estimate. Others have run into a similar problem, and have suggested [this site](http://www.huduser.gov/portal/datasets/usps_crosswalk.html) publishing spreadsheets mapping various administrative codes to ZIP codes, but none seem to match the ones used by NYT.

My GEOIDs look like (e.g. for the area around Norristown, PA):

```
42091-NORRISTOWN 1-3
42091-NORRISTOWN 1-2
42091-NORRISTOWN 1-1
42091-HATFIELD 3-2
42091-HATFIELD 3-1
```

etc.

If I download `ZIP_TRACT_122020.xlsx` from huduser.gov, it has data like:

| ZIP | TRACT |
| --- | --- |
| 19426 | 42091206703 |
| 19426 | 42091206702 |
| 19426 | 42091206104 |
| 19426 | 42091206007 |

etc.

If I cross reference the first 5 digits of the GEOID, e.g. "42091", they do seem to be in the very rough area of the ZIP codes in the spreadsheet. However, it's the last digits of the Tract number that I can't match.

I'm guessing the GEOID used by NYT and the TRACT number used by huduser.gov have a 1-to-1 mapping, where the trailing digits represent a town and subdivision, but I can't find a way to link them.

How do I do this? Is there a better way to cross reference GEOID to ZIP code?

Answer (score 1):

Voting districts can be matched to ZIP codes by their coordinates.

To get an approximate result I suggest the following algorithm:

- Calculate voting district coordinates by averaging its polygon coordinates.
- Add data about ZIP code coordinates. I downloaded it [here](https://simplemaps.com/data/us-zips).
- Match voting districts to the closest ZIPs.

Python implementation

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from scipy import spatial
import math

def load_precincts_geojson():
    return json.load(open('./precincts-with-results.geojson'))

def load_zip_coordinates():
    df = pd.read_csv('./uszips.csv')

    return df[['zip', 'lat', 'lng']]

def get_geo_id_coordinates_from_geojson(geojson):
    recs = []
    for item in geojson['features']:
        all_coordinates = flatten_coordinates(item['geometry']['coordinates'])
        coordinates = np.array(flatten_coordinates(item['geometry']['coordinates']))
        rec = {
            'geo_id': item['properties']['GEOID'],
            'lat': np.mean(coordinates[:, 1]),
            'lng': np.mean(coordinates[:, 0])
        }
        recs.append(rec)

    return pd.DataFrame(recs)

def flatten_coordinates(arr):
    if type(arr[0]) != list:
        return [arr]

    result = []
    for sub_arr in arr:
        for coord in flatten_coordinates(sub_arr):
            result.append(coord)
            
    return result

def get_closest_location_indexes(left_df, right_df):
    result = []
    left_sphere_coordinates = [
        location_sphere_coordinates(row['lat'], row['lng'])
        for _index, row in left_df.iterrows()
    ]
    right_sphere_coordinates = [
        location_sphere_coordinates(row['lat'], row['lng'])
        for _index, row in right_df.iterrows()
    ]
    # kd-tree much more faster than pairwise comparison
    tree = spatial.KDTree(right_sphere_coordinates)
    for left_coordinate in left_sphere_coordinates:
        _dist, index = tree.query(left_coordinate)
        result.append(index)

    return result

def location_sphere_coordinates(lat, lng):
    lat = math.radians(lat)
    lng = math.radians(lng)
    x = np.cos(lng) * np.sin(lat)
    y = np.sin(lng) * np.sin(lat)
    z = np.cos(lat)

    return (x, y, z)

precincts_geojson = load_precincts_geojson()
precincts_coordinates = get_geo_id_coordinates_from_geojson(precincts_geojson)

zip_coordinates = load_zip_coordinates()

closest_zip_indexes = get_closest_location_indexes(precincts_coordinates, zip_coordinates)
geo_id_to_zip = pd.DataFrame({
    'geo_id': precincts_coordinates['geo_id'],
    'zip': np.array(zip_coordinates['zip'])[closest_zip_indexes]
})
```

[image: precincts_coordinates]
[image: zip_coordinates]
[image: geo_id_to_zip]

Answer (score 1):

The first 5 digits of the GEOID are the FIPS code, and you have the full list available here linked with the ZIP code, county name, etc.

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/danofer/zipcodes-county-fips-crosswalk?resource=download

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm not sure all the 5-digit codes are FIPS. Many are not in that dataset (like "06031"), so either the dataset is incomplete, or my list contains other codes.